# Sink drain collecting water? Too small?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I recently installed a new vanity and purchased a faucet and push drain for them. They don't leak, and everything works well.

However, it appears as if the top of the drain in the basin isn't properly sized for the sink hole, or the sink hole has some issues. I'm not sure which is the issue as I researched both products and didn't find anyone discussing this issue.

Would a plumbing silicone around the edge solve for the standing water, or is this okay? You can see a slight gap on the drain.

[Sink Drain Images full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn3qO.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please embed one or more images here rather than making us click out to another site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the sink slipped past quality control. Or quality control just sorts who they send the bad sinks to, rather than junking them, depending (I may be a bit jaded on poorly made plumbing fixtures from major brands with blatantly obvious defects...)

The "correct fix" is to return the defective sink for a replacement. The standard install method is to use plumbers putty, though some fixture manufacturers now recommend silicone instead, but in neither case should you need to fill a divot like that in an area not covered by the drain flange.

Comment: Dang, that sucks. The window to return this product closed as it took a while for the bathroom that was being worked on to get to the place where the sink was ready to be installed.

Do you know if there are any other solutions to this?

Comment: Fill it with silicone and have a sink that looks like your slumlord installed it, or replace it are the options as I see them. Might measure carefully and visit a Habitat Restore to see if you get lucky on an expensive sink at a low price... You might also **try the manufacturer directly.** Even if it's past the store return time, they may acknowledge the slip-up and send you a new one anyway.

Comment: Appreciate it! Going with the return route. I'm sure with a defect like this they'd at least be able to do that.

Comment: This sort of defect will be couvered by any reasonable warranty.